# Node.js request method callback

Tags: node.js, callback

client.get method does not work in redis for node.js

```
//blog function
module.exports = {
  index: function () {

    var data = new Object();
    data.ip = base.ip();

    var redis = require("redis");
    var client = redis.createClient(6379,'192.168.33.10');

    client.get("foo",function(err,reply,callback)
    {
      var x=reply.toString();
    });

    data.y=x;


    return data;
  }


};
```

`data.y="bar"` expects but

`x is not defined.`

where is the problem?

Comment: I can't understand it the link that you gave

Comment: @dm03514 is right, you need to understand javascript nature that is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `client.get` is an asynchronous method, which you can't return from. You need some sort of asynchronous control flow, such as callbacks.

```
//blog function
module.exports = {
  index: function (callback) {
    var data = new Object();
    data.ip = base.ip();
    var redis = require("redis");
    var client = redis.createClient(6379, '192.168.33.10');
    client.get("foo",function(err,reply) {
      if(err) return callback(err);
      data.y = reply.toString();
      callback(null, data);
    });
  }
};
```

You'd then use it like

```
var obj = require('./whatever');
obj.index(function(err, result) {
  //result will contain your data.
});
```